# Sunspot Rails and Carrot2

Tags: sunspot, sunspot-rails, carrot2

I'm using the sunspot_rails gem for a rails application. Is there a way to integrate the cluster engine carrot2 into a rails app? Obviously carrot2 is part of sunspot as it is commented in the solr configs. But I'd like to know wheather someone has already integrate it.